# SQL how to compare a table to itself

Tags: sql

So lets say I have a table with this information in it

```
 - Tom   BLDG200
 - Kevin BLDG200  
 - Mary  BLDG340
```

I want to find everyone who shares the same building. So I want it to print out Ton and Kevin. But because Mary is by herself it shouldn't print. The way I have been going about it is using INNER JOIN to join them at the buildings but because I am comparing a table to itself it joins even if it's only 1 person. So in my case it would print out Mary even though I don't want it to. How can I make it print out only if 2 or more people share the same building.

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem?

Comment: Is this what the value looks like in a column? `- Tom   BLDG200`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff If you read the question, OP said *"The way I have been going about it is using ..."*

Comment: It usually helps to know what database are you working on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an efficient way to solve this query:

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1
              from table t2
              where t2.name <> t.name and t2.building = t.building
             ) ;
```

This will optimally take advantage of an index on `building, name`.

Most databases offer window/analytic functions, which are another efficient approach:

```
select name, building
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by building) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column names are `person` and `building`:

```
SELECT t1.person, t2.person 
  FROM `table` t1 
       JOIN `table` t2 
            ON (    t1.building = t2.building 
                AND t1.person > t2.person
                );
```

This line `AND t1.person > t2.person` solves your problem with Mary.
There is a problem with more persons, beacause they would be divided into pairs. But if this doesn't bother you, that would work.

Also, followind would work (but results appear per person, so you'll have list of every non-lonely persons and buildings they live in)

```
SELECT t1.person, t1.building 
  FROM `table` t1 
       JOIN `table` t2 
            ON (    t1.building = t2.building 
                AND t1.person > t2.person
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

Relational algebra 101. I added some more names so you can see that `distinct` is needed. In my sample data only Jane is alone and should not be in result.

```
with cte (name, building) as (
values
 ('Tom',  'BLDG200'),
 ('Kevin','BLDG200'),
 ('John', 'BLDG200'), 
 ('Jack', 'BLDG200'),  
 ('Mary', 'BLDG340'),
 ('Terry','BLDG340'),
 ('Jane', 'BLDG341')  
)

select 
  distinct
  a.name, a.building 
from 
  cte a 
  join cte b on (a.name <> b.name and a.building = b.building)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/1525)

Comment: I feel really stupid now. I was doing it correctly but I made the mistake of thinking it wasn't returning the right results when it was